# Pyqgis 3: Trying to Update Attribute with Value but Getting Index out of Bounds

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm able to successfully add attributes with an expression to my vector layer using:

```
#Add fields to get evaulated based on an expression
vectorLayer.addExpressionField("'R'",
QgsField("rtype",QVariant.String, 'string', 11))

vectorLayer.addExpressionField("y(point_on_surface($geometry))",
QgsField("lat", QVariant.Double, 'double', 20, 7))

vectorLayer.addExpressionField("x(point_on_surface($geometry))",
QgsField("long", QVariant.Double, 'double', 20, 7))

vectorLayer.addExpressionField("\'Comment explanation; type: {}\'".format(type), QgsField("comment",QVariant.String))

vectorLayer.updateFields()
```

Then based on a select by location I need to update the comment value, so I get the indexes using:

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(1)
features = vectorLayer.getFeatures(request)

#Get indexes for attributes we are keeping 
for feature in features:

     rTypeIdx = feature.fields().indexFromName("rtype") 

     latIdx = feature.fields().indexFromName("lat")

     longIdx = feature.fields().indexFromName("long")

     commentIdx = feature.fields().indexFromName("comment")
```

To update the comment accordingly I use:

```
selectedFeatures = vectorLayer.selectedFeatures()

for feature in selectedFeatures:

     fid = feature.id()

     #Get comment index and value for updating attribute values 
     commentIdx = feature.fields().indexFromName("comment")

     commentValue = 'Comment value'

     attributes = {commentIdx: commentValue}

     feedback.pushInfo("Updating feature {} with attributes{}".format(fid,attributes))
     vectorLayer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({fid: attributes})
```

After I run my script everything works, except I get the warning that my attribute index for the comment is 10 out of bounds [0;7].  I've verified this index using several different methods including feature.fields().indexFromName("comment").  They all return the index value of 10 which is the last attribute.  If I hardcode the value of 7 for my index it crashes QGIS.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the correct index value to update this field without getting an index error? I'm using QGIS version 3.x.

EDIT:  I'm now trying to update my feature using

```
vectorLayer.startEditing()
featureUpdated = vectorLayer.changeAttributeValue(fid, commentIdx, commentValue)
vectorLayer.commitChanges()
```

This is also failing by returning False.

Comment: since you are changing only one value you can try to use: vectorLayer.changeAttributeValue(fid, commentIdx, commentValue)

Comment: The changeAttributeValue method for vectorLayer just seems to silently fail.

Comment: It seems like since I used the vectorLayer to add my fields using a QgsExpression that I need to continue to update the layer this way instead of using the dataProvider.  By mixing these two my indexes don't appear to be matching up.